# jquery validator still closes when not valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I made a modal with a form in it I check if the form is valid by doing `.valid();` even tough when you do something wrong and field turns red so jquery validator detected you did something wrong it still returns `true` I have been searching why this is happening for 1 day now. I figured maybe one of you guys or girls know.

here is a working snipplet https://jsfiddle.net/jgytud7h/6/

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :** If you fill in the first field and select a type. it will close even tough the form is not valid in my eyes.

HTML:

```
<span class="data-label" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adddnsmodal" onclick="">Add DNS</span>                                 <div class="modal fade" id="adddnsmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add DNS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="modalvalidate" name="validatemodal1">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="domainadd" class="form-control" value="test" disabled>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Domain</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="extadd" class="form-control" value="nl" disabled>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Extention</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="nameadd" class="form-control subdomain" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Sub domain</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="contentadd" class="form-control" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Content</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" id="prioadd" class="form-control prio" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Prio</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" id="ttladd" class="form-control onlynumbers" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">TTL</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="typeadd">
                            <option value="notselected" selected disabled>Select a type</option>
                            <option value="A">A</option>
                            <option value="AAAA">AAAA</option>
                            <option value="CNAME">CNAME</option>
                            <option value="MX">MX</option>
                            <option value="SOA">SOA</option>
                            <option value="TXT">TXT</option>
                            <option value="SRV">SRV</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="adddnssave">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
.validator.addMethod("subdomain", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?$/i.test(value);
    },"<strong>Error! </strong>Invalid subdomain.<span></span><button type='button' class='close' onclick='removeMSG()' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>");

$.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/i.test(value);
    },"<strong>Error! </strong>Invalid domain.<span></span><button type='button' class='close' onclick='removeMSG()' aria-      label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>");

$.validator.addMethod("prio", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^(10|1)$/i.test(value);
    },"<strong>Error! </strong>Invalid Prio.<span></span><button type='button' class='close' onclick='removeMSG()' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>");

$.validator.addMethod("onlynumbers", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]+$/i.test(value);
    },"<strong>Error! </strong>Field Must contain only numbers<span></span><button type='button' class='close' onclick='removeMSG()' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>");




 $('form[name*="validate"]').validate({
        errorElement:'div',
        errorClass: 'alert alert-danger',
        validClass: 'alert-success',
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.addClass('messagediv2');
            error.addClass('page-controls');
            error.insertAfter("h4.modal-title");

        }
    });
    $('form[name*="validate"]').on('change', function(){
        $(this).validate();
        if ($(this).valid) {
            $(".messagediv2").remove();
        }
    });




 $('#adddnssave').on('click', function () {
        $('#adddnssave').prop('disabled', true);

                if ($('#typeadd').val() != 'notselected'  && $('#typeadd').val() != null) {
                    if ($('form[name*="validate"]').valid()) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "",
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                domain: $('#domainadd').val(),
                                ext: $('#extadd').val(),
                                name: $('#nameadd').val(),
                                type: $('#typeadd').val(),
                                content: $('#contentadd').val(),
                                prio: $('#prioadd').val(),
                                ttl: $('#ttladd').val()
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (response) {
                                var message =
                                    '<div class="page-controls alert alert-success" style="top:50px;position:relative;border-radius: 0 0 0.25rem 0.25rem;">' +
                                    '<strong>' + response + ' </strong> <span>DNS is successfully added</span>' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">' +
                                    '<span aria-hidden="true" onclick="removeMSG()" >&times;</span>' +
                                    '</button>' +
                                    '</div>';
                                $('#adddnsmodal').modal('hide');
                                $("#navbarmenue").after(message);
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $('#adddnssave').prop('disabled', false);
                                }, 2000);

                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $('#adddnssave').prop('disabled', false);
                                }, 1500);
                                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown, 'error');

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#adddnssave').prop('disabled', false);
                             var message =
                                    '<div class="page-controls alert alert-danger" style="top:50px;position:relative;border-radius: 0 0 0.25rem 0.25rem;">' +
                                    '<strong>' + response + ' </strong> <span>Modal is not valid</span>' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">' +
                                    '<span aria-hidden="true" onclick="removeMSG()" >&times;</span>' +
                                    '</button>' +
                                    '</div>';
                                $("#navbarmenue").after(message); 
                    }


                } else {
                    var message =
                        '<div class="page-controls alert alert-danger messagediv2">' +
                        '<strong>Error </strong> <span>Select a type</span>' +
                        '<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">' +
                        '<span aria-hidden="true" onclick="removeMSG()" >&times;</span>' +
                        '</button>' +
                        '</div>';
                    $("h4.modal-title").before(message);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#adddnssave').prop('disabled', false);
                    }, 1500);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code into your question.  Simply posting a jsFiddle without also posting the relevant code is not good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky we already solved it. and that was the whole problem i didnt know where the error was

Comment: I know you already solved it and the relevant code is in your jsFiddle above.  However, there is good reason we have certain rules here, like when the jsFiddle goes dead.  The question is just not helpful to futures readers in its present form.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky whats not clear about me not knowing where the error is thats why i put a jsFiddle in because i had no idea i forgot the name attribute in the code sould i put all the code here to...?

Comment: @Sparky edited like this then?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  For future reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle example you are checking for a valid form but valid is not a property but a function.

change this:

```
if ($('form[name*="validate"]').valid) {
```

to

```
if ($('form[name*="validate"]').valid()) {
```

example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ry5m9zck/1/)

Update: Another problem was that mandatory name attribute for jquery validation was missing. Adding name attribute fixed the issue.

Comment: this is the most stupid error i have ever made and seached for so long i am so sorry. Thank you very much tough for your response legend!

Comment: it actually does not work i tried but it doent hide because yours has a error i went for lunch after i tought it worked sorry for the late reponse

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain or edit question.

Comment: as shots as possible the question here: All i want is to not do the ajax request when the form inside the modal is not valid. So it has to be with my regexs and no red fields. Thats all @SSA

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/2xo0214e/1/ I added the name attribute to fields. Check here the markup recommendation, name attribute is a must https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/

Comment: That is the solution! the name apperantly helps. Thank you BIG BIG time i was woking on this for so long thanks! edit your solution so i can make it the solution!